# Batch file to grow folder numbers incrementally

Tags: windows-7

I am trying to create a batch file that will create a folder system titled 17-001 - 17-999 on the desktop.

How do I tell the folder to go to 17-002 if 17-001 already exists?

Comment: Welcome to Superuser! We are not a script writing service, but we may be able to help with scripts you have already written that may need some assistance. Can you demonstrate to us what your current script looks like and what part isn't working?

Comment: Hints: [md](http://ss64.com/nt/md.html) and  [for /l](http://ss64.com/nt/for_l.html)

Comment: If you use `for /f %%d in ('dir /ad /b') do set dir=%%d`, then after this command `%dir%` will contain the highest numbered directory in use. Now you have simply to extract the last three characters and increment the numeric value to derive the next number to use (with special handling to create the directory name for values under 10 and under 100). See [this link](https://ss64.com/nt/syntax-substring.html) for information on variable expansion and [this](https://ss64.com/nt/set.html) on arithmetic with variables.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
@echo off
Echo starting . . .
Set num=001
:loop
If exist “C:\Users\%username%\Desktop\17-%num%” echo Skipped [17-%num%]&goto Reloop
Md “C:\users\%username%\Desktop\17-%num%\”
Echo created [17-%num%]
:reloop 
If %num%==999 go to endloop
set /a num+=1
Goto loop
:endloop
Echo done
Pause
Exit /b
```

I’m not sure if it will keep the zeros or not, can’t test yet.

Also, while it is true this isn’t supposed to be a script writing service, a script is defined as multiple lines of code so often we ask for and get scripts, just not a finished product. I get that you didn’t know where to start so you asked here, and I think people need to jump to conclusions and judgment less here. Hope I could help.